# T-SQL Paging Sorting & Filtering - Filtering not Working

Tags: t-sql, sorting, filtering, paging

T-SQL Paging Sorting & Filtering

I have been working on a T-SQL stored procedure for a number of hours now that will enable me to retrieve a paged set of articles that are sorted in ASC or DESC order based on a specified column.

I am now working on getting the stored procedure to filter based on the first character of the 'Title' field and have added the lines:

```
@StartAlpha nvarchar(1) = null
```

and

```
WHERE ((@StartAlpha IS NULL) OR (Title Like @StartAlpha + '%'))
```

see below.

The stored procedure no longer returns any results. And I don't really know why.

Can anyone please help?

Regards

Walter

```
USE [ABC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Get_MyArticles_Paged]    Script Date: 08/07/2011 20:41:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_MyArticles_Paged]

    /*Paging Total For Output*/
    @Row_Count BIGINT OUT,

    /*Paging Inputs*/
    @Page_Size INT = 10,
    @Page_Number INT = 1,

    @Sort_Column VARCHAR(100),  /* ('articleid','createdate','title','subject') */
    @Sort_Direction VARCHAR(4), /* ('ASC','DESC') */

    @StartAlpha nvarchar(1) = null

AS

BEGIN
print @StartAlpha
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*========================================================================
    Declare local variables
    ========================================================================*/
    DECLARE @FirstRecord int
    DECLARE @LastRecord int

    -- create a temporary space for paged result set
    DECLARE @PagedResults AS TABLE (
        [ArticleID] INT,
        [CreateDate] SMALLDATETIME,
        [Title] VARCHAR(200),
        [Subject] VARCHAR(500),
        [Row_Number] BIGINT,
        [Row_Count] BIGINT
    );

    /*========================
    Normalize Paging Parameters
    ==========================*/
    --Fix invalid input for Page Size
    SET @Page_Size = CASE 
        WHEN @Page_Size IS NULL THEN 10
        WHEN @Page_Size < 1 THEN 10
        ELSE @Page_Size
    END;

    --Fix invalid input for Page Number
    SET @Page_Number = CASE
        WHEN @Page_Number IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN @Page_Number < 1 THEN 1
        ELSE @Page_Number
    END;

    --starting record to use.
    SET @FirstRecord = ((@Page_Number - 1) * @Page_Size) + 1

    --last record to use.
    SET @LastRecord = @FirstRecord + @Page_Size - 1

    --ensure sort column is valid in the list
    SET @Sort_Column = CASE
        WHEN LOWER(@Sort_Column) IN ('articleid','createdate','title','subject')
                THEN LOWER(@Sort_Column)
            ELSE
                'title' --default
    END

    --ensure sort direction is ASC or DESC
    SET @Sort_Direction = CASE
        WHEN LEFT(UPPER(COALESCE(@Sort_Direction, '')) + '    ', 4) = 'DESC' 
            THEN 'DESC' --explicit descending
        WHEN @Sort_Column = 'created' AND LEFT(UPPER(COALESCE(@Sort_Direction,'')) + '   ', 3) <> 'ASC' THEN
            'DESC' --default for created date
        ELSE 'ASC' --default otherwise
    END;

    /*============
    Prepare Results
    ==============*/
    WITH [MyTempArea] AS (
    SELECT TOP (@LastRecord)
            [ArticleID],
            [CreateDate],
            [Title],
            [Subject],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='articleid'      THEN [articleid] END END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='createdate'     THEN [createdate] END END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='title'          THEN [title] END END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='subject'    THEN [subject] END END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='articleid'     THEN [articleid] END END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='createdate'        THEN [createdate] END END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='title'         THEN [title] END END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='subject'   THEN [subject] END END DESC
            ) AS [Row_Number],
            COUNT(*) OVER () AS [Row_Count]
        FROM Articles
        WHERE ((@StartAlpha IS NULL) OR (Title Like @StartAlpha + '%'))  
    )

    INSERT INTO @PagedResults
    SELECT * FROM [MyTempArea] WHERE [Row_Number] >= @FirstRecord;

    /*===========
    Return Results
    =============*/
    -- @Row_Count output param
    SELECT @Row_Count = COALESCE(MAX(Row_Count), 0) FROM @PagedResults;

    -- Paged results set to return
    SELECT [ArticleID],[CreateDate],[Title],[Subject]
        FROM @PagedResults
    ORDER BY [Row_Number];

END
```

Comment: Can you ensure that you haven't changed anything but those two lines? Remove them and ensure that you get results. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with either of them, at first glance.

Comment: Yes Sam. By removing those lines I get all rows returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that made helpful suggestions.

I completely refactored the stored procedure and it now works.  See below.

I'm not entirely sure why the original Stored Procedure didn't work and why this version does, but I thought I would share with the forum.

Thanks again.

Walter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Account_ContactGetData]
    @CurrentPage int = null,  
    @PageSize int = null,  
    @SortColumn nvarchar(max) = null,
    @SortDirection varchar(5),
    @StartAlpha nvarchar(1) = null

WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @FirstRecord int;
        DECLARE @LastRecord int;

    --starting record to use.
    SET @FirstRecord = ((@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize) + 1;

    --last record to use.
    SET @LastRecord = @FirstRecord + @PageSize - 1;

with ContactCTE as
(
    SELECT [ContactID], [DisplayName], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName],    
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By

    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='ContactID' AND @SortDirection='DESC' THEN ContactID END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='ContactID' AND @SortDirection='ASC' THEN ContactID END ASC,

        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='DisplayName' AND @SortDirection='DESC' THEN DisplayName END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='DisplayName' AND @SortDirection='ASC' THEN DisplayName END ASC,

        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='FirstName' AND @SortDirection='DESC' THEN FirstName END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='FirstName' AND @SortDirection='ASC' THEN FirstName END ASC,

        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='MiddleName' AND @SortDirection='DESC' THEN MiddleName END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='MiddleName' AND @SortDirection='ASC' THEN MiddleName END ASC,

    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='LastName' AND @SortDirection='DESC' THEN LastName END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn='LastName' AND @SortDirection='ASC' THEN LastName END ASC 

    )) AS Row
    FROM Contact
    WHERE
    ((@StartAlpha is NULL) OR (LastName Like @StartAlpha+ '%'))  
)   
SELECT [ContactID], [DisplayName], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName]
    FROM ContactCTE
WHERE Row BETWEEN @FirstRecord AND @LastRecord  

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on those requirements alone, this is what I would do:

```
WHERE ((@StartAlpha IS NULL) OR (LEFT(Title, 1) = @StartAlpha))
```

What do you get when you run just this part? (Please also state which values you are using in your parameters)

```
WITH [MyTempArea] AS (
SELECT TOP (@LastRecord)
        [ArticleID],
        [CreateDate],
        [Title],
        [Subject],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='articleid'      THEN [articleid] END END ASC,
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='createdate'     THEN [createdate] END END ASC,
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='title'          THEN [title] END END ASC,
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'ASC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='subject'    THEN [subject] END END ASC,
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='articleid'     THEN [articleid] END END DESC,
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='createdate'        THEN [createdate] END END DESC,
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='title'         THEN [title] END END DESC,
                CASE WHEN(@Sort_Direction = 'DESC') THEN CASE WHEN @Sort_Column='subject'   THEN [subject] END END DESC
        ) AS [Row_Number],
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS [Row_Count]
    FROM Articles
    WHERE ((@StartAlpha IS NULL) OR (Title Like @StartAlpha + '%'))  
)
SELECT * FROM [MyTempArea]
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I tried this and it still doesn't work. When I do: SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE ((LEFT(Title, 1) = 'd')) it works. Must be something wrong with my CTE.

Comment: @Walter Do you get any rows when you run only the query in the CTE?

Comment: Yes. I get all rows returned.

Comment: @Walter You're query is doing `SELECT * FROM [MyTempArea] WHERE [Row_Number] >= @FirstRecord;`, but in your example code `@FirstRecord` is null?

Comment: @Andreas... `SET @FirstRecord = ((@Page_Number - 1) * @Page_Size) + 1` ? It's right there in the SP

Comment: Hi Andreas. For some reason the stackoverflow code editor wasn't displaying those lines. Take a look now.

Comment: @Walter What do you get when you run the part I added to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas `LEFT(Title, 1)` syntax would perform better than the like comparison... but using the like, this should work:

```
WHERE (Title Like isnull(@StartAlpha, '') + '%')
```

(The combination of working with nulls that `OR` makes me edgy.)