# how to pass Order By @col name through variable in a paging enabled Query

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, paging

Following is a Paging enabled Query for SQL server, it is working well without dynamic **order by @pOrderBy** variable .

I want to implement two things in this query.

1. I want to sort the rows according to the column name i m passing.
2. I want to run another Query in it to get total number of rows so that I can display number of pages on my UI.

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_get_all_groups] 
     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @pStartIndex smallint,
     @pPageSize tinyint,
     @pOrderBy varchar(20)
   AS
   BEGIN
     -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
     -- interfering with SELECT statements.
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT       GroupTable._id,
                 GroupTable.GroupCode,
                 GroupTable.Type,
                 GroupTable.Description
       From(
       Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          ORDER BY UG._id,
               UG.GroupCode,
               UG.Type,
               UG.Description ) as [Row_Number],
               UG._id,
               UG.GroupCode,
               UG.Type,
               UG.Description
      From UserGroups as UG
      ) as GroupTable
      where GroupTable.[Row_Number] BETWEEN @pStartIndex AND @pStartIndex + @pPageSize             
      ORDER BY GroupTable.[Row_Number]

   END
   ```

Comment: I have to put "order by @pOrderBy" at some place , but i can't figure out where, I tried by placing it just after "From UserGrroups as UG" statment (4th last in Query) , but i m getting error

Comment: Why a procedure instead of a view? you can then pass in parameters for the where and manage the order by on your own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to sort the rows according to the column name i m passing.

You will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for that - it is not possible to use a column name in a variable on a regular query.

An alternative is to use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause - checking the value of the variable and using the corresponding column. See the comment from @Dems.

> I want to run another Query in it to get total number of rows so that I can display number of pages on my UI.

Use an [output parameter or return value](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_&_Return_Values) and assign the value of such a query to it in this stored procedure.

Comment: thanks @Oded my question is somewhat similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983350/t-sql-paging-sorting-filtering-filtering-not-working

Comment: This isn't quite right.  You *can* use `ORDER BY CASE WHEN @col = 'col1' THEN col1 END, CASE WHEN @col = 'col2' THEN col2 END, etc, etc`.  This avoids the maintenance cost of dynamic SQL, but often yields extremely poor execution plans.  This means that it *is* suitable if the result sets are small, but is possibly unsuitable for large result sets.

Comment: @Dems - Yes, you can use `CASE`, but you still have to specify the column name as a _column_, not a variable.

Comment: @Oded - As it's a fixed table, one already knows the fixed list of columns to sort by, so one can create all the CASE statements necessary that you can pick which to sort by using a variable.

Comment: @Dems - I don't deny this. But the case statement checks a variable against a constant in order to determine what column to sort by - it does not use the variable directly as the column to sort.

Answer (score 3):

1. You cannot order by the variable's value
2. There are different techniques to do paging and ordering by custom column, there are two most usable (IMHO):

   - use dynamic querying
   - use CLR **User Defined Aggregate** which accepts the value of sorting field, sorting direction, Page number, Page Size and ID of the record, and finally returns the set of IDs which combines the needed page with sorting applied - also it can return total number of rows in the same query.